# Update ksql stream with new topic schema

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, ksqldb

I write avro messages into kafka topic using schema registry.
Then created stream based on the topic. The scream created with current schema.

Then I add new field to the schema. The schema register updated, it's OK, but the stream stay with the first structure.

Can I update the stream with new schema?

It's problematic for me to drop and create the schema again because I have lot of other streams\tables that depend on it. The KSQL don't allow to drop stream with dependencies.

Comment: Can you just create a new stream now that you have the new schema in place? Once you have the new stream (based on the new schema) you can point your applications to this new stream.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is stop the streams and DROP STREAM MYSTREAM.

https://docs.confluent.io/current/ksql/docs/developer-guide/create-a-stream.html#delete-a-ksql-stream

Comment: Care to collaborate a little more why do you think it's the best solution?

Comment: Drop stream is not option for me because I have lot of dependencies ( read the questions again).